# "Save someone's life" in German

Tags: grammar, translation

I want to tell a story and in a part I want to say:

> He saved his owner's life.

I'm not sure if this sentence is correct:

> Er hat dem Besitzer das Leben gerettet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, "to save sb's life" is translated as "jdm. das Leben retten" and, hence, your German sentence is correct.

Except for two minor mistakes. Note that *his* is translated as *seinem*, while *dem* is the translation of the article *the*.
Also, it is *gerettet* at the end of the sentence. I guess this was just a typo, wasn't it?